# What does "Culture Devourer" mean?

Tags: meaning

So I've seen this expression in a sentence which <strike>seems to be a career</strike>. Can anyone tell me what does it mean?

> Poya was in his earlier days a culture devourer. He once went to a record store and bought a box of Beethoven’s symphonies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a career, it's a characteristic (which could cross over into a pastime).  It simply means that they enjoy listening to/reading/watching etc a lot of "cultural items", which could include music, films, books, theatre etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture

Usually when people say "culture" in this context they're referring to things which are seen as more "highbrow" or intellectual, such as classical music, poetry, classic novels, theatre, opera etc, but you also have "popular culture" which includes blockbuster movies etc.  It's not clear exactly which kind is being referred to in the text - for all we know the person in question could enjoy listening to some Beethoven and then go to the local megaplex cinema to watch the latest summer blockbuster.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the meaning of "[devour](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/devourer)" (dictionary.com)

> to take in greedily with the senses or intellect:
>    - to devour the works of Freud.

It refers to someone who is a big "consumer" of culture (books, music, shows etc.) generally for personal pleasure, not as a profession.